# Pourquoi « sans-dents » a-t-il été utilisé pour indiquer les pauvres ?

Tags: expressions

Récemment, un certain personnage public a été « accusé » d'utiliser cette expression en privé pour indiquer les pauvres.

Je ne comprends pas trop quelle est l'analogie? Est-ce parce que les pauvres ont plus de difficulté à accéder aux soins dentaires ou il fait référence à quelque chose d'autre?

Comment: La presse du jour commente largement l'expression avec un article du journal [*Le Monde*](http://www.lemonde.fr/les-decodeurs/article/2014/09/04/les-sans-dents-ou-la-difficulte-de-l-acces-aux-soins-dentaires_4481347_4355770.html) sur la question des soins dentaires.

Comment: À préciser que cette expression sort de la tête de celui à qui on l'a faite dire et qu'elle ne fait référence à rien d'autre qu'au coût des soins dentaires.

Comment: Ceci n'est pas une expression consacrée en français, mais une appréciation personnelle de celui qui l'a formulée et son emploi est du ressort de l'analyse sociologique et pas une question de français  *stricto censu*.

Comment: Question trop tendancieuse. Et puis comme l'indique Laure, on trouve des explications simples (bien qu'orientées) dans la presse ou autres flux d'informations sur la toile.

Comment: Tendancieuse pourquoi? D'abord j'ai pas cité les personnes en question et on en parle partout, donc pas besoin de faire de la "pub".  J'ai pas exprimé aucun jugement, donc ça serait tendancieux juste d'en parler? Au sens propre ça me semblait une façon de parler plutôt naïve et je me demandait si il y avait un sens figuré. Reste toujours a savoir si l'éxpression à été inventé par l'auteur du livre ou par son personnage...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En français, plusieurs tranches de la société sont ou ont été construites sur le même modèle, par exemple, les *sans-culottes*, les *sans-papiers* ou les *sans-abri*.

Ce n'est donc pas difficile de comprendre l'allusion, ne serait-ce qu'à travers l'image de Fantine dans *Les Misérables* de Victor Hugo, qui a vendu sens dents.

Selon le contexte il est également tout à fait possible d'employer sans-dents pour les vieillards ou les nouveau-nés.

Answer (score 2):

Les soins dentaires sont effectivement trop onéreux pour beaucoup de personnes. Ils dépendent beaucoup de la mutuelle de la personne. Les personnes avec peu de ressources n'ont souvent pas accès à une mutuelle remboursant suffisamment ce type de soin (peu remboursé par la Sécurité Sociale).

C'est souvent un indicateur de la classe sociale de la personne (mais pas systématiquement).

Le [lien fourni en commentaire par Laure](http://abonnes.lemonde.fr/les-decodeurs/article/2014/09/04/les-sans-dents-ou-la-difficulte-de-l-acces-aux-soins-dentaires_4481347_4355770.html) résume bien la situation à travers diverses statistiques.